# Is there any process for informing the community about StackExchange members who have passed away?

Tags: discussion

A good friend of mine, who was also active on StackExchange, passed away a couple of days ago.

Does SE have any sort of process in this scenario, or do SE profiles sort of live on forever?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry about your friend.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thankyou, his name was [Dermot](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1134136/dermfrench), he was my boss/mentor for a number of years

Comment: JMK, I'm really sorry for your loss. I know that little offers true solace when a friend or loved one is lost, but please pass on to those close to him that his generosity here reached over 100k people in need of help. (Part of the idea for the "people reached" stat was borne out of a desire to let a user's family understand how much good they'd done online, sharing what they knew with others.) In any case, my sincere condolences.

Comment: Thankyou @Jaydles I actually introduced him to SE so I feel pretty good about that, see you about the Exchanges :)